# Orthonormal Vectors with Respect to an Inner Product

Tags: statistics, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

I am given an inner product defined as the following image:
[Inner product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lim8H.png)

I have already found the range of the values of α and β.
For the following question, I do not know how to approach the problem.
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEV5Q.png)

It would be great if I am provided with steps alongside with a full solution.
The concept of orthonormality with a 1 dimensional real value is confusing me. Moreover, I may be misunderstanding the question but v1 and v2 are not orthogonal and I am puzzled on how to show orthonormality in the first place.

Thank you very much and again, I would like a **full solution** provided as my understanding may not be complete in this particular problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: What did you get for the inner product of $v_1$ and $v_2$? You are supposed to choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so as to make the vectors orthonormal.